# wrong in my script for download?

Tags: python

I write this script

```
import urllib
urllib.urlretrieve("URL","path\ name.jpg")
```

It's working
But if there is no internet it's make wrong 
I want it if there is no internet.  wait to connect by internet then work again

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Try to always provide info what you did (that's included), what happened (missing) and what you expected to happen instead (unclear).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write something like this:

```
def wait_for_internet_connection():
    while True:
        try:
            response = urllib2.urlopen('http://google.com',timeout=1)
            return
        except urllib2.URLError:
            pass

def main():
    #your code here

wait_for_internet_connection()
main()
```

The while loop will execute until there's an active internet connection, then executes your code.